# Не работает datetimepicker(jQuery)

Tags: jquery, плагин

Подключаю jquery таким образом:

```
<script src="jscore/jqui/jquery-1.7.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jscore/js/jquery.bgiframe-2.1.js"></script>
<script src="jscore/jqui/ui/jquery.ui.core.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jscore/jqui/ui/jquery.ui.widget.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jscore/jqui/ui/jquery.ui.tabs.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jscore/jqui/ui/jquery.ui.datepicker.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jscore/jqui/ui/i18n/jquery.ui.datepicker-ru.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jscore/datatable/jquery.dataTables.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jscore/jqui/ext/timepicker.addon.js"></script>
<script src="jscore/jqui/ui/jquery.ui.dialog.js"></script>
<script src="jscore/jqui/ui/jquery.ui.mouse.js"></script>
<script src="jscore/jqui/ui/jquery.menu.js"></script>
<script src="jscore/jqui/ui/jquery.position.js"></script>

<script src="jscore/jqui/ui/jquery.ui.sortable.js"></script>
<script src="jscore/jqui/ui/jquery.ui.draggable.js"></script>
<script src="jscore/jqui/ui/jquery.ui.resizable.js"></script>

<script src="jscore/jqui/ui/jquery.effects.core.js"></script>
<script src="jscore/jqui/ui/jquery.effects.drop.js"></script>
<script src="jscore/jqui/ui/jquery.effects.blind.js"></script>
<script src="jscore/jqui/ui/jquery.effects.explode.js"></script>
```

А вот таймпиккер не работает, собака. Обычный ui календарь работает. Они могуть как-то конфликтовать? Таймпиккера скачал с сайта `http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/`.

Вызываю так:

```
$('#example9').datepicker({});
$('#example16').timepicker({});
```

Comment: Что пишет firebug console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Зачем такая свалка, каждый модуль из UI отдельно подключаете? Подключите одним файлом все

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

Может в этом и проблема...